# Create a folder in document library using REST (Java)

Tags: document-library, rest, folder

How do you create a folder in document library. I got this code right now but getting error code 403 FORBIDDEN

```
public void createFolder(String digest) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
    HttpPost request = new HttpPost(
            "http://industrial-ex/sites/tifdemo/_api/Web/Folders/add('enovia/newfolder')");
    request.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;odata=verbose");
    request.addHeader("X-RequestDigest", digest);
    request.addHeader("Accept", "application/json;odata=verbose");
    CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(target, request, context);
    System.out.println("STATUS CODE: " + response.getStatusLine());
}
```

Comment: The documentation states that a site relative url will work, strange that it does not here.  Have you tried a server relative url or the method [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn450841.aspx#code-snippet-54)?

Comment: The method you mentioned

Comment: Sorry i edited the question. i get error code 403 forbidden

Comment: Oh, should've asked the obvious, do you have the authorization token?

Comment: The Digest you mean?

Comment: How are you getting the digest?  I haven't tried using Java before, but with C#, the authorization token is required with the request digest.

Comment: Like this:
https://gist.github.com/Abdiliban/deb8a13d03b6268c72f4

Comment: Is it SharePoint online or on-premises?

Comment: It is on-premises

Comment: Anyone got a answer?

Comment: @eirikb do you got time again? :P

Comment: @wjervis you got any answer to this sir?